# Better query using WHERE IN () when param can be nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

For example we have model **TableRow - columns (:account_number, :month, :department, :phone_number)**. And have a method that returns filtered rows by arrays of this params.
For required params we can use

```
TableRow.where('account_number IN (?)', param)
```

Is there best way to add in this query unrequired params (department, phone_number) that can be nill and we should return records with any params in this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to approach this. If you want your query to be static, you can check the literal value of your param with the SQL logic itself:

```
TableRow.where('COALESCE(:depts) IS NULL OR department IN (:depts)', depts: param)
```

You can also build up your relation incrementally in Ruby:

```
relation = TableRow.all
relation = relation.where(department: depts) if depts.present?
```

Comment: The way with  COALESCE is very helpful for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but if what you want is to filter by phone_number while still retrieving records where phone_number is null, you just have to that:

```
TableRow.where('phone_number IN (?)', param << nil)
```

Comment: This won't work. `c in (v1, v2)` is equivalent to `c = v1 or c = v2` but `X = null` evaluates to `null` for all `X` (even when `X` is `null`) and `null` isn't truthy in SQL. You're also modifying `param` and that's generally a bad idea.